# getting sum of textbox 1 and 2 into textbox 3

Tags: php

I have three text boxes and I want to place a value in textbox 1 and 2,then add them together and get the result in textbox 3.With the below code I can get it to echo out onto the screen,but If I omit the echo then nothing happens after placing numbers in T1 andT2.
Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <br>
    <form name="myform" action="textentry2.php" method="POST">
        <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "go">
        <input type = "text" name = "text1" >
        <input type = "text" name = "text2" >
        <input type = "text" name = "text3"  >

<?php

$text_entry = $_POST['text1'];
$text_entry2 = $_POST['text2'];
$text_entry3 = $_POST['text3'];

{
   $text_entry3 = ($text_entry + $text_entry2);
   echo ($text_entry3);
}

?>
```

Comment: You want the numbers to populate the form after submission? Move your form below the PHP code and use `value="<?php echo ($text_entry3); ?>"`

Answer (score 2):

> nothing happens after placing numbers in T1 andT2

PHP is a server-side language. you can't expect from PHP to act real-time...

input values need to go to server, then PHP Server can calculate your values on server then after refresh, results comes...

if you want to write a real-time calculator, you need to write this with javaScript. absolutely you can do that with AJAX or anything else but javaScript is a easy and fast way for this.

try this:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>My Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<form name="myform" action="textentry2.php" method="POST">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value = "go">
<input type="text" name="text1" onkeyup="calc()">
<input type="text" name="text2" onkeyup="calc()">
<input type="text" name="text3"    >
</form>
<script>
function calc()
  {
    var elm = document.forms["myform"];

    if (elm["text1"].value != "" && elm["text2"].value != "")
      {elm["text3"].value = parseInt(elm["text1"].value) + parseInt(elm["text2"].value);}
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Zargaripour.Thankyou for your answer,your code is very instructive and works great

Answer (score 1):

### For Strings:

```
$text_entry3 = ($text_entry.$text_entry2);
```

in php you combine strings with a . between them.

### For Integer:

```
$text_entry3 = ((int)$text_entry + (int)$text_entry2);
```

You need to cast them as you get Strings from your from and they won't add together that easy without casting.

### For Placing it:

as Aravona stated allready:
You should make all the calculation befor you output the html. Php is dynamic. HTML not. Thus you need to put the dynamic part into the static one

Make the `<?php ... ?>` in the beginnin and than use this to output the result:

```
<input type = "text" name = "text3" value="<?=$text_entry3;?>" >
```

Comment: No need to cast them explicitly, PHP will cast them automatically when trying to use them as numbers.

Comment: @ChristianF it should. But He stated that with the `echo` noting happend. Thus I assumed that the automatic cast doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code would be like this:

```
<?php
$text_entry1 = (int)$_POST['text1'];
$text_entry2 = (int)$_POST['text2'];
$text_entry3 = ($text_entry1 + $text_entry2);
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Page</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <br>
        <form name="myform" action="textentry2.php" method="POST">
        <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "go">
        <input type = "text" name = "text1" value = "<?php echo $text_entry1 ?>" >
        <input type = "text" name = "text2" value = "<?php echo $text_entry2 ?>" >
        <input type = "text" name = "text3" value = "<?php echo $text_entry3 ?>" >
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is the simplest way, but it's better doing it with AJAX in JavaScript.

Comment: Whether or not it's better is a question of personal taste. It's different, and it will provide the user with an immediate result, instead of having to send it via a web-server. That's true. However, if @colin is using the above code to learn PHP, then doing it in JS would be rather pointless, imho. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly put your PHP above your HTML so the values are defined. 
Then:

```
<input type = "text" name = "text3" 
  value="<?php echo ((int)$text_entry + (int)$text_entry2); ?>">
```

Comment: many thanks for your reply Henry,a nice little instructive code snippet :)

Answer (score 0):

A very good tips I tend to give those who are new to PHP, is to put *all* of your PHP code before any HTML. This means that you'll take care of all of your data processing, before you try to send the client anything. The beauty of that, is that if some erroneous condition appears, you can simply redirect or do whatever's necessary to provide the user with a clear and informative responce. Instead of just dumping a half-created page, with an ugly error (or several) in the middle of it.

Thus your PHP code should look something like this:

```
<?php

// First make sure that the variable is defined, to prevent notices
// when trying to use it later.
$answer = '';

// If something has been posted (submitted).
if (!empty ($_POST)) {
    // Calculate the answer.
    // TODO: Add some validation to make sure that the values are indeed numbers.
    // See filter_var () in the PHP manual.
    $answer = $_POST['text1'] + $_POST['text2'];
}

?>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myform" action="textentry2.php" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value = "go">
    <input type="number" name="text1" >
    <input type="number" name="text2" >
    <input type="number" name="text3" value="<?php echo $answer; ?>">
</form>
```

Normally I'd use `htmlspecialchars()` on `$answer` when echoing it, to prevent XSS attacks. However, since it only echo out a number it is not necessary in this case.

Comment: Hi Christain F,Overwhelmed by all of the replies:) many thanks for your reply,and it works great